# Dynamic PlotRange in Animate not working properly

Tags: animation

I'm trying to do an animation of a graphic showing a ball rolling down a 20 deg. ramp. I've set up a `PlotRange` that moves as time evolves, so it will follow the ball. The animation works properly for a bit, and then breaks.

Here's the relevant code. I've removed everything except a fixed, dashed line representing the ramp.

```
Animate[
   pR = {5 t^2 Cos[20 \[Degree]] + {-10, 
 10}, -5 t^2 Sin[20 \[Degree]] + {-4, 4}};
  Graphics[
    {
      {Dashing[{0.1, 0.13}],
       Line[{{0, 0}, 135 {Cos[20 \[Degree]], -Sin[20 \[Degree]]}}]}
    },
    PlotRange -> pR,
    PlotLabel -> pR
  ],
 {t, 0, 6}
]
```

The `PlotLabel -> pR` inside the `Graphics` shows that `pR` is updating, but the animation of the line stops for a while.

I'm using Mathematica 12 under Mac OS 10.13.

Any ideas?

Comment: The plot range changes to the point that the "ramp" gets out of view, yes, but that's by design isn't it? Can you explain how it "breaks", i.e. what you would expect instead?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent. But when I run it, the line appears to be moving, until the slider control gets about a quarter way across. Then the line appears to simply stop, remaining until the slider is almost all the way across, at which point, the line moves again, until it gets out of view. I don't think this in an aliasing issue, since it remains stopped for a wide range of "speeds".